# Save multiple models in a single post - Django rest frameweok

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 4 models

```
class User(AbstractEmailUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()

class EventLocation(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    ubigeo = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)

class EventStaff(models.Model):
    recycler = models.ForeignKey(User)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

When I want to register an event and be able to assign users to this same publication at the time of creation, assign users or do not assign them. I have already created a **nested serialier** that in the documentation is well explained so that the event is saved and at the same time it is saved in the ubigeo field of the EventLocation table (code of the district of the place):

```
Class EventLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EventLocation
        fields = ('id', 'ubigeo')

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
event_location = EventLocationSerializer(required=True, write_only=True)

def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(EventSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    event_location = EventLocation.objects.filter(event=instance.id)
    if event_location:
        representation['event_location'] = event_location.values('ubigeo')[0]
    return representation

class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ('id', 'date', 'name', 'address', 'schedule', 'event_location')

def create(self, validated_data):
    location_data = validated_data.pop('event_location')
    event = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)
    EventLocation.objects.create(event=event, **location_data)
    return event
```

and it works correctly, but how would you add the users you want to assign to the event at the same time? I know I have to save them in the **EventStaff** table but how do I insert them in that same post?

This is my **viewset**:

```
@transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            try:  
                data = request.data
                serializer = EventSerializer(data=data)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response({"status": True, "results": "Evento registrado correctamente"},
                                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except ValidationError as err:
                return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the json format:

```
{
    "date": "2018-03-01",
    "name": "La prueba reciclaje",
    "address": "Av españa trujillo",
    "users": [
        {"id": 40, "first_name": "Raul"},
        {"id": 23, "first_name": "ALejandro"}
    ],
    "eventlocation": {
        "ubigeo": ["130101"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, we can custom your def create a bit more.
So we create one Serializer for User, get params user and save it after Event saved.
Maybe like this:

```
@transaction.atomic
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
        try:
            data = request.data
            serializer = EventSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
                // recheck , this loop have input is all users in json
                for user in data.get('users'):
                    user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user)
                    if user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                        user_serializer.save()
                return Response({"status": True, "results": "Evento registrado correctamente"},
                                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except ValidationError as err:
            return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hoop this help

Comment: Thank you very much for answering but I do not need to create a new user, I just want to relate that user who is a user already created to the event. But you have given me an idea.

Comment: I think I'll get the pk of the event after creating and with a for I get the ids of the json users. Saving them in the eventstaff table.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the commentary, it works wonderfully :D

```
@transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            try:  
                data = request.data
                users = request.data.get('users', None)
                serializer = EventSerializer(data=data)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    instance = serializer.save()
                    if users:
                        for user in users:
                            EventStaff.objects.create(recycler_id=user['id'], event_id=instance.id)
                    return Response({"status": True, "results": "Evento registrado correctamente"},
                                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except ValidationError as err:
                return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```